# Changing char arrays in a struct variable in the header file from the C file messes up the arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I have a normal .c file, and also a .h header file.

Here is part of my .c file code, with comments explaining what the output looks like at every step. This is in the main function:

```
FreqType freq;

    freq.andLiteral[0] = 'a';
    freq.andLiteral[1] = 'n';
    freq.andLiteral[2] = 'd';
    freq.andLiteral[3] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", freq.andLiteral); //Outputs: and

    freq.theLiteral[0] = 't';
    printf("%s, ", freq.theLiteral); printf("%s\n", freq.andLiteral); //Outputs: t, and
    freq.theLiteral[1] = 'h';
    printf("%s, ", freq.theLiteral); printf("%s\n", freq.andLiteral); //Outputs: th, and
    freq.theLiteral[2] = 'e';
    printf("%s, ", freq.theLiteral); printf("%s\n", freq.andLiteral); //Outputs: the, and
    freq.theLiteral[3] = '\0';
    printf("%s, ", freq.theLiteral); printf("%s\n", freq.andLiteral); //Outputs: the, and

    freq.ofLiteral[0] = 'o';
    printf("%s, ", freq.ofLiteral); printf("%s, ", freq.theLiteral); printf("%s\n", freq.andLiteral);
    //Outputs: o, theo, and 
    freq.ofLiteral[1] = 'f';
    printf("%s, ", freq.ofLiteral); printf("%s, ", freq.theLiteral); printf("%s\n", freq.andLiteral);
    //Outputs: ofand, theofand, and
    freq.ofLiteral[2] = '\0';
    printf("%s, ", freq.ofLiteral); printf("%s, ", freq.theLiteral); printf("%s\n", freq.andLiteral);
    //Outputs: of, theof,
```

And here's the relevant part of my .h header file:

```
typedef struct {
    char theLiteral[3];
    char ofLiteral [2];
    char andLiteral [3];
    int theCounter, ofCounter, andCounter;
} FreqType;
```

What goes wrong with changing the arrays that the arrays tend to mix with each other?

Comment: For starters, you're accessing all of your arrays out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks, 'twas a stupid error!

Answer (score 2):

Your field declarations are too small. For example, theLiteral needs to allow **4** characters including the \0 at the end, so you need to write

```
char theLiteral[4]
```

and so forth.